# Overnight script returning scripting error 201 at Set Field

Tags: filemaker

I have a script setup to run overnight on my Filemaker server, but every night it returns this error:

> Schedule "Recheck All Flags" scripting error (201) at "MasterDatabase : Recheck All Flags : ### : Set Field

Where ### is just a random number, probably the line in the script. In the above example let's just say it was 398.

I can't copy and paste the script to here, but it is very simple. It's one big loop over all records in the database and it checks a bunch of `If` statements. It looks like:

```
If [MasterDatabase::Start date = ""]
    Set Field [MasterDatabase::Flagged for Discrepancy; "Yes"]
    Commit Records/Requests [With dialog:Off]
End If
```

Why might this be failing when running on the server overnight?

Comment: You're asking us to guess. I would check the target field's type and the possibility of records being locked.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I'm happy to provide more details. The field type is text. And why would the records be locked? I'm not familiar with how scripts run overnight. When I run the script manually, it works just fine.

Comment: *"And why would the records be locked?*" Because another user is editing them.

Comment: @michael.hor257k The script runs at 12:00 AM when all users are away from work and out of the system, even if it were the case that one person left their computer on and a record was locked out, this error occurs far too frequently for that to be the case.

Comment: Those are my guesses. Without being able to reproduce the problem, that's all I can do.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you tell the server to go to the correct layout before the script starts, when the server starts up the script it will do the work on the layout that it is configured for the DB to open by default.

You can do something like:

```
If [ $$PLATFORM = "Server" ] 
    (Go to Layout X)
End If
```

The global variable $$PLATFORM can be defined in your On First Window Open Script like so:

```
Case (
PatternCount ( Get ( ApplicationVersion ) ; "Server" ) ;
"Server" ;
PatternCount ( Get ( ApplicationVersion ) ; "Data API" ) ;
"Data API" ;
Get ( SystemPlatform ) = 4 ;
"Web" ;
Choose (
    Get ( Device ) ;
    "Desktop" ; // 0 - Unknown
    "Desktop" ; // 1 - Mac      
    "Desktop" ; // 2 - PC
    "Tablet" ; // 3 - Tablet
    "Phone" // 4 - Phone
)
```

)

If you already have that covered then make sure whatever user you are using for the PSOS has access to that layout, records scripts and fields.

Comment: Why is layout relevant in a script like this? The startup script in the database already goes to the layout I want it to be on (where all the fields are).